# getJSON not getting data from database

Tags: getjson

```
function find()
{
   var id = $('#Id').val();
   $.getJSON("api/questionsanswer/" + id,
   function (data)
   {
       var str = data.Username + ': $ ' + data.Questions;
       $('#questionanswer').text(str);
   })
   .fail (
       function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
       $('#questionanswer').text('Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

I try to get the data it display "null: null"
so it seems that data.Username and data.Questions wasn't capture... what is wrong with my code??

Comment: Have you checked what your server returns?

Comment: the server return null: $ null

Comment: No, that's what you're trying to print. I was asking what the server returns. The actual, raw data.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob... hmmm the raw data I was trying to print is all string format..

*realize something... the database server have the "X" there everytime I try to run it... but have already done a check on the connectionstrings